# How to validate a drop down list which has been populated with data using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[id$=ddljobtype]").append("<option value='-1'>-- SELECT --</option>");
    $("select[id$=ddljobtype]").append("<option value='Private'>Private</option>");
    $("select[id$=ddljobtype]").append("<option value='Government'>Government</option>");
    $("select[id$=ddljobtype]").append("<option value='Entrepreneur'>Entrepreneur</option>");
    $("select[id$=ddljobtype]").append("<option value='Farmer'>Farmer</option>");
});
```

How can this drop down list in this case ddljobtype be validated in asp.net?

Comment: Define "validated".  What are you trying to validate?  How are you trying to validate it?

Comment: validated??? meaning, explain

Comment: What do you want to validate the list with?

Comment: In the above code the ddljobtype drop down list is to be validated in an asp.net form where I want to check whether the user has selected any value or not? If the user has not selected any value then using builtin validation control of asp.net, I would request them to select some value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this valeu in the same way you define the options on it

```
function valideMe(){
   var selectedval = $("select[id$=ddljobtype]").val();
   if(selectedval =="someValue"){
       //to do
   }
}
```

Then invoke the action by clicking in a button

```
<button onclick="valideMe()">
```

Comment: In the above code the ddljobtype drop down list is to be validated in an asp.net form using buitin asp.net validation controls. By validation I mean to check whether the user has selected any value or not? If the user has not selected any value then using builtin validation control of asp.net, I would request them to select some value.

Comment: I dont want to validate it using Jquery but using builtin asp.net validator.